# Defining endpoints accessible without requiring user authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

i've wanted to make a authentication in spring security, but i've wanted some of the requests to be available for everyone on the site (main page, login and register). Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
package com.shapesynergy.dietworkout.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.SessionManagementConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.    requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/register").permitAll().
                                requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Sites that i want to be available for everyone

```
package com.shapesynergy.dietworkout.noauth;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NoAuthenticationSites {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register() {
        return "register";
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String mainPage() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

i've tried to follow some guides, but almost everything is depricated already

Answer (score 0):

In the requestMatcher() method, the URL patterns are not correct.

Try this:

```
req.requestMatchers("/**", "/login/**", "/register/**")
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, when i use "/**", it opens all other patterns, but when i use only "/login/**" and "/register/**" it's blocked again

Comment: Can you share more logs when trying to access endpoints?

Comment: I've got it, the problem was, that the order of requests matter, and i had to make "/**" last